# How to print page content to next page after reaching page size in html-docx-js?

Tags: html, node.js, docx

when trying to add a page break in html-docx-js using inline style css property it does not work.

inline style css for page break doesn't seem to work.
`<br style="page-break-before: always; clear: both" />`

```
      const GENERATE_UUID = uuidv4();

      const path = `generated/letter_list_${GENERATE_UUID}.docx`;

      let converted_html = htmlDocx.asBlob(letter_list.parsed_html_string);

      const html_buffer = await converted_html.arrayBuffer();

      const doc_url_promise = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        async function createDoc(html_buffer, parsed_html_string) {
          writeFile(path, parsed_html_string, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err);
              return;
            }
          resolve()
          });
        }
        createDoc(html_buffer, letter_list.parsed_html_string);
      });

      const document_url = await doc_url_promise;
```